# How to fix''local variable 'result' referenced before assignment''

Tags: python, python-3.5

```
      8     if n != 0:
      9         y = n%10 #figure out the least number like 12345 is 5
---> 10         result.append('y')
     11         get_digits(n//10)#like 12345 becomes 1234
     12
```

local variable 'result' referenced before assignment

how can i fix it?thank for your help

if i do this,it will work:

```
result = []
def get_digits(n):
        if n>0:
               result.insert(0,n%10)
               get_digits(n//10)

get_digits(12345)
print(rsult)
```

This is my last code,it has a mistake,but i can't fix it

```
## input 12345 ,output[1,2,3,4,5]

result = []#define a empty list

def get_digits(n):    
    if n == 0:
        result = list(reversed(result))#reverse the list，if not output[5,4,3,2,1]
        return result
    if n != 0:
        y = n%10#figure out the least number like 12345 is 5
        result.append('y')
        get_digits(n//10)#like 12345 becomes 1234

print(get_digits(12345))    

[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Tell python `result` is a `global` variable:

```
result = [] #define a empty list

def get_digits(n):
    global result  # add this line here to reference your result variable above
    if n == 0:
        result = list(reversed(result)) #reverse the list，if not output[5,4,3,2,1]
        return result
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `result` is defined outside of your function, in the global scope, so your function isn't able to assign to the variable. You can explicitly allow this by adding a `global result` statement:

```
result = []

def get_digits(n):  
    global result  
    # ...
```

`print(get_digits(12345))` will still not work though, since `get_digits(n//10)` doesn't return anything; you'll need something like

```
get_digits(12345)
print(result)
```

However, instead of using a global variable, I would recommend defining `result` within your function and returning it, as well as returning when you call `get_digits` recursively within your function.

```
def get_digits(n):
    def helper(result, n):
        if n == 0:
            result = list(reversed(result))
            return result
        else:
            result.append(n % 10)
            return helper(result, n // 10)
    return helper([], n)
```

Then, `print(get_digits(12345))` will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an empty variable locally in the function solves this error.

**For Example:**

```
def string_splosion(str):
  for i in range(len(str)):
    result = result + str[:i+1]
  return result
```

This caused me error: "local variable '**result**' referenced before assignment"

This clearly states that the variable '**result**' is not defined to store the iterative value. So I need to declare a string variable in the function similar to the below code.

```
def string_splosion(str):
      result = "" #This line proned to error.
      for i in range(len(str)):
        result = result + str[:i+1]
      return result
```